# Extrema of sum of 2 sinusoidal functions with different periods

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, roots, maxima-minima

I would like to find the extrema of this function:
$f(x) = w \cos(x) - (1-w)\cos(\alpha x)$. You can assume $w \in (0, 1)$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.

Alternatively one could find the zeros of this function:
$f'(x) = -w\sin(x)+\alpha(1-w)\sin(\alpha x)$.

There are ways to solve this numerically, but is there a (simple) analytical formula for the solution (e.g., depending on $w$ and $\alpha$)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a simple analytical formula? Making the derivative of f(x) equal to zero seems a simple analytical solution to me.

Comment: @Unique I mean in the form $x = \phi(w, \alpha) + 2 \pi n, n \in N$